# Asp.Net Button postback keeps firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

For some reason the postback event keeps firing for my button. If I place a break point on the function(e) part with Firebug, the code just skips right over the function.
Return false does not work either.

```
<script>
$(document).ready
(
$('#<%:FilterButton.ClientID %>').click 
  (
    function (e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#Filter').toggle();
    }
   )
 );
</script>
```

**Edit:**
Kundan and others have pointed out that I skipped passing in an anonymous function  for the document.ready() event. Careless on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#<%= FilterButton.ClientID %>').click(function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#Filter').toggle();
      return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few issues with your code, unless it was just a bad copy/paste job. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#<%=FilterButton.ClientID %>').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#Filter').toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Correct! Skipped the initial anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#<%:FilterButton.ClientID %>').click
```

to

```
$('#<%=FilterButton.ClientID %>').click
```

Comment: That unfortunately does not make a difference.